# Can I use a REST API with permalink setting, "plain"?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, wordpress-rest-api

I want to post articles to a WP site without permalinks, meaning the permalinks are set to "plain" in the permalink setting, from my application. I know that if I access "https://site-domain.com/?rest_route=/", JSON will be returned. However, even if I access "https://site-domain.com/?rest_route=/oauth1/request", JSON is not returned.

This means that I can access the endpoint of the REST API, but I am unable to obtain the necessary authorization to access it.

Is it not possible to use the REST API from an external application with the permalinks set to "plain"?

I tried:

1. Set permalink as "plain" on permalink setting
2. Accessed to "https://site-domain.com/?rest_route=/" and could see json returned
3. Accessed "https://site-domain.com/?rest_route=/oauth1/request" and see 404. (Meaning I cannot access to the url. If I set the other permalink setting, I can see message like cannot get oauth token or something, meaning I can access to the url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [get_rest_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/) in your cases.